# using eval in PHP with multidimensional array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, eval

I have a array that I am writing to a file using `var_export()`. I reload the array every time the script starts. However, whenever I try to reference a variable inside the array it returns 'a', I can do a `print_r()` and see the array just fine, I just can not access the variable I want. Here is the saved output:

```
array (
  'timestamp' => '1283882964',
  'files_submitted' => 2943,
  'errors' => array (
                     '/WebFS/xx.doc' => array (
                                                                                                                                                         'STATUS' => 400,
                                                                                                                                                  ),
                     'WebFS/xx.doc.doc' => array (
                                                                                                                                                                  'STATUS' => 400,
                                                                                                                                                            ),
              )
)
```

Here is the code I use to save:

```
function add_log_entry($filename,$return_arr) {
        //$timestamp = strval(mktime());
        $return_arr['timestamp'] = mktime();
        $return_str = var_export($return_arr,true);
        return file_put_contents($filename, $return_str);
}
```

Here is the code I use to recall the array:

```
function get_log_entry($filename) {

        $var_str = file_get_contents($filename);
        eval("\$return_var = \$var_str;");
        die($return_var['timestamp']);
        return $return_var;
}
```

You can see I put the `die()` in the recall code and this is where the 'a' is coming from.

Thanks to whom ever responds.

Ben

Comment: Why do you use an array you cannot refer to? Ever considered to use a less complex (for you) structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>use the php functions [`serialize`](http://php.net/serialize) and [`unserialize`](http://php.net/unserialize), no need to write your own hacks using `var_export` and `eval` (apart from the security implications)</strike>

example code:

```
 file_put_contents($filename, serialize($array));
 $array = unserialize(file_get_contents($filename));
```

Using `serialize`/`unserialize` might impose a security risk. To serialize simple arrays/data structures it's better to use the [`json_encode`](http://php.net/json_encode) function:

```
 file_put_contents($filename, json_encode($array));
 $array = json_decode(file_get_contents($filename), TRUE);
```

Comment: This answer is old and outdated. `unserialize` might impose security risks. If you just need to serialize an array, better use `json_decode`